# New reccomended version of VLC and Make MKV Blu Ray work around?

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

So one of the reccommended solutions to get Ubuntu to play Blu Ray is to setup VLC to  work with MakeMKV translating and streaming output  in the background as described here.

https://www.howtogeek.com/240487/how-to-play-dvds-and-blu-rays-on-linux/

However as far as I have been able to tell the newest versions of MakeMKV no longer have the streaming feature available that made this work.

Are there other solutions to this problem?? or older Linux versions of MakeMKV to make this doable ???.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is too old but if it can help: the new way is to install makemkv from instructions here https://forum.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224

This will install a shared library libmmbd.so that vlc can use.
Run makemkv first to accept the 30 days trial or use the license from here:
https://forum.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1053
Check that it detects your blu-ray disc.

Then just start VLC, select open disc, blu-ray and your blu-ray drive, it should just work (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with makemkv 1.16.5).